# How would i get the subpath from a specific directory from a path?

Tags: java, algorithm, refactoring

Okay I can't quite word it, but i need the following:

`C:\Temp\Something\GroupName\...\file.ts -> GroupName\...\file.ts`

I want to extract the path from a folder till the end.

I came up with this disaster right here, but I am sure i am reinventing the wheel.

```
private Path extractGroupPath(Path path, String groupName) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < path.getNameCount(); i++) {
        if (path.getName(i).startsWith(groupName)) {
            break;
        }
    }
    Path groupPath = Paths.get("");
    for (; i < path.getNameCount(); i++) {
        groupPath = groupPath.resolve(path.getName(i));
    }
    return groupPath;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I can follow. If you have a full path and need to strip some parts at the front where's the problem? If you have a path and want to get the contents then you'd have to consider that there may be more than one path with the same parent path, e.g. `C:\Temp\Something\GroupName\...\file1.ts`,  `C:\Temp\Something\GroupName\...\file2.ts` etc. What exactly are you after and why? There might be an easier, more standard solution if we'd know what your ultimate goal is.

Comment: I want to get the subpath of a path and that subpath should begin with the groupName

Comment: In that case you could try to iterate through the parents to get the group's path (via `getParent()` and checking the path's filename) and if you've find it you should be able to get the relative path in that group via `parentPath.relativize(path)`.

Comment: You are a genius thanks, if you want post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: You're welcome - done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the a relative path between to paths you can use the `relativize()` method.

Thus you should be able to do this once you've found the base path, which - if you don't know it already - could be done by iterating through the parents (using `getParent()`) until you find it (by checking `getFilename()`) or hit the root. Then it should be as easy as `parentPath.relativize(path)`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer Thomas gives is awesome and does what I needed, but in the end I decided this:

```
   public Path extractGroupPath(Path path, String groupName) {
        int startIndex = path.toString().indexOf(groupName);
        String groupPath = path.toString().substring(startIndex);
        return Paths.get(groupPath);
    }
```

Because it is more simple and easy to understand.